# windows phone app webview doesnot responds geolocation

Tags: c#, webview, windows-phone-8.1, geolocation, microsoft-appstudio

my mainpage.xaml.cs code

i have created this web view app for windows phone 8.1 on appstudio.windows.com and i tried to edit the code in visual studio 2015. i want that the geolocation should work on the webpage integrated in the webview. The phone is showing location icon but not able to retrive geocordinates.I have turned on location capabilities in manifest. Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong.

Any help will save me. Thanks in advance.

```
    using System;
    using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;
    using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;
    using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
    using CFORCABSOfficial.ViewModels;
    using CFORCABSOfficial.Wat;
    using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;

   namespace CFORCABSOfficial.Views
   {

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private MainViewModel _mainViewModel = null;
        private DataTransferManager _transferManager = null;
        private Uri _currentUri = null;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

            _mainViewModel = _mainViewModel ?? new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = this;
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().
            SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible);


            var splash = App.CurrentSplashScreen;
            if (splash != null)
            {
                // Optional: Add a progress ring to your splash screen to show users that content is loading
                PositionRing();
            }

            WatConfig.LoadConfigAsync(this.MainWebView, this.BottomCommandBar);
            this.MainWebView.NavigationCompleted += OnFirstLoadNavigationCompleted;
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += OnBackPressed;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            _transferManager = _transferManager ?? DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
            _transferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            _transferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
        }

        private void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            _mainViewModel.GetDataShare(args.Request, _currentUri);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles back button press.  If app is at the root page of app, don't go back and the
        /// system will suspend the app.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the BackPressed event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details for the BackPressed event.</param>
        private void OnBackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            var RootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (RootFrame == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (RootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                RootFrame.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (this.MainWebView.CanGoBack)
            {
                string url = MainWebView.Source.ToString();

                String url2 = "http://windows.xyz.com/member-index.php";
                String url3 = "http://windows.xyz.com/index2.php";
                if ( url != url2) 
                { 
                MainWebView.Navigate(new Uri("http://windows.xyz.com/member-index.php"));
                    e.Handled = true;
               }
if (url == url3)
                { App.Current.Exit(); }
if (url == url2)
                { App.Current.Exit(); }
            }
        }

        #region "ExtendSplashScreen"
        void PositionRing()
        {
            splashProgressRing.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Window.Current.Bounds.Width / 2.2);
            splashProgressRing.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 5);
        }
        #endregion

        public MainViewModel MainViewModel
        {
            get { return _mainViewModel; }
        }

        private void OnFirstLoadNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            this.MainWebView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.loadingCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.BottomAppBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            this.MainWebView.NavigationCompleted -= OnFirstLoadNavigationCompleted;
            this._currentUri = args.Uri;

            this.MainWebView.NavigationStarting += OnNavigationStarting;
            this.MainWebView.NavigationCompleted += OnNavigationCompleted;

            _transferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;

        }

        private async void OnNavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
            await statusBar.ProgressIndicator.ShowAsync();
            Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
            {
                Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
                Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
            }
  }


        private async void OnNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            this._currentUri = args.Uri;
            var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
            await statusBar.ProgressIndicator.HideAsync();
            // Carry out the operation.

        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: ever found a solution?